# How do I run the sqlite3 insert statement once in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test3.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""create table if not exists test(
num integer primary key autoincrement,
name char(5))""")

cursor.execute("insert into test(num, name) values(null, 'andy')")
conn.commit()    

for i in cursor.execute("select *from test"):
if int(i[0]) <= 1:  
    conn.commit()
else:       
    conn.close()
```

I put the sqlite3 value in `wx.combobox`, choices and have the changed value applied to sqlite3 when the `wx.combobox` value is changed. I have a problem during operation and want to fix it.

When you run the program
`cursor.execute ("insert into test (num, name) values ​​(null, 'andy')")` This statement continues execution. How do I get my program to run once when I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you do not need to pass the number in query as it is set to autoincrement.

Comment: I did not think autoincrement was appreciated.